# request.getParameter() returns null

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf

Got a homework assignment that is giving me problems....  Its modifying a JSF project with two pages and a bean to fit MVC2 by adding two more pages and a controller servlet and another bean for the two additional pages.  the new main page forwards to either the second new page or the old first page.  My issue is response.getParameter() always results in null.

```
<%@page session="false" import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<jsp:useBean id="status" scope="request" class="JSFRegistration.Status" />
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% if (status!=null && !status.isSuccessful()){%>
            <font color="red">Processing errors:
                <ul><%Iterator errors=status.getExceptions();
            while (errors.hasNext()){
                Exception e = (Exception) errors.next();%>
                <li><%= e.getMessage()%><%}%></ul></font><%}%>
        <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
            <% String username = request.getParameter("username");
            if (username==null) username="";%>
            <input type="text" name="usernameTF" value="<%=username%>" />
            <% String password = request.getParameter("password");
            if (password==null) password="";%>
            <input type="password" name="passwordTF" value="<%=password%>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

this is basically a direct copy from our book but the fields I need for the new main page.  Same for the controller servlet, a direct copy except only contains the fields I need.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher view = null;
    Status status = new Status();
    request.setAttribute("status", status);
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if (username==null || username.length()==0)
        status.addException(new Exception("Please enter username"));
    if (password==null)
        status.addException(new Exception("Please enter password"));
    if (!status.isSuccessful()){
        view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
        //view.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
        try{
            request.setAttribute("username", username);
            request.setAttribute("password", password);
        view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Registration.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status.addException(new Exception("Error"));
            view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
        }
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

and the Status class, again a direct copy from the book.

```
public class Status {
private ArrayList exceptions;

public Status(){
    exceptions = new ArrayList();
}
public void addException(Exception exception) {
    exceptions.add(exception);
}
public boolean isSuccessful(){
    return (exceptions.isEmpty());
}
public Iterator getExceptions(){
    return exceptions.iterator();
}
```

regardless of what is typed into the two boxes, stepping through a debug shows the values not getting passed to the parameters.  I get the created exceptions printed above the screen for both fields if both have text, if only one has text and when both are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request parameter names do not match the input field names. You've assigned the input fields a name of `usernameTF` and `passwordTF`. They are then available by exactly those names as request parameter, but you're attempting to get them using the names `username` and `password`. So you need either to fix the input field names, or the request parameter names so that they match each other.

By the way, why falling back from a modern MVC framework like JSF to awkward 90's style JSP with mingled business code? Is that *really* what the homework assignment is asking you? Also the HTML `<font>` element is deprecated since 1998. Where did you learn about it? Is the quality of the course really good?

Comment: Ah, completely overlooked that.  Honestly, I've been falling behind somewhat, the book and the extra content are outdated.  The book isn't any help with JSF as it shows everything when Visual JSF was supported in NetBeans and it isn't in NetBeans 7.  It doesn't give any code and what I've posted here is a copy from the extra content as it is the closest example we have without putting in the extra work to learn on our own.  The class isn't required, I'm only taking it as it is the more interesting class of some elective classes for a certification.

Comment: You can find JSF tutorials in our JSF tag wiki page. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info I'd also discuss with your tutor about the quality of the course materials. I'd be really surprised if this is what the assignment expects.

Comment: And there's a big learning curve with it, the pre-req doesn't cover alot of stuff this class expected us to know already, both use the same book.

Comment: No tutor, college course.  I guess being a 400 level, we're expected more to go out on our own and learn stuff when the book doesn't help.  We have alot of people complaining about the book and extra content in the class and how the instructor puts out our assignments.

Comment: "Visual JSF" is also known as "Woodstock" and it died 5 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/woodstock/info The course material is definitely far outdated which would only confuse yourself more when you're attempting to search for solutions/answers on Google as that usually returns the more recent results only. Also, JSF 2.x related results may confuse you more as the programming approach has completely changed since JSF 2.0. As said, check the JSF tag wiki page. At the bottom you can find decent tutorial links, e.g. coreservlets.com.

Comment: Thanks.  Working on converting everything from JSP to JSF like the rest of it.