# request.getParameter returns null value: servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my html code for `<form>`

```
 <form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/admin/company/add" id="add-form" name="add-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" ></textarea>
     <textarea class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" ></textarea>
     <input class="form-control" name="contact_person" placeholder="Contact Person" type="text" >
     <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Epost" type="email" >
     <input class="form-control" name="web" placeholder="Website url" type="text">
     <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="text" >
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Telefax" name="telefax" type="text"  >
     <button type="submit" class="btn green btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
</form>
```

and this is my code in servlet's `doPost()` method

```
CompanyEntity  companyEntity = new CompanyEntity();
companyEntity.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
companyEntity.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
companyEntity.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
companyEntity.setWeb(request.getParameter("web"));
companyEntity.setContactPerson(request.getParameter("contact_person"));
companyEntity.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
companyEntity.setTelefax(request.getParameter("telefax"));
```

> Error- All values to the entity are null

what's the error here, how to fix it.

What i read- 
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283282/request-getparameter-returns-null) , 
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231999/request-getparameter-returns-null-in-jsp) , 
[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149757/request-getparameter-returns-null-in-servlet) , 
[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639576/request-getparameter-returns-null-in-java-servlet-on-calling-it-from-another-s)

Comment: Are you uploading files too?

Comment: no... but enctype="multpart/form-data"

Comment: Why not use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're posting the form as `multipart/form-data`. Since it doesn't seem like you're uploading any files, change it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or remove it altogether since this is the default).

Alternatively, add some sort of multipart request filter/wrapper to your application so that it processes multipart requests and provides access to the request parameters.

Comment: Ok means problem may be with enctype ... let me check ... sorry for late response

Comment: I think I need to handle enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1):

remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your from tag

Answer (score 0):

And the name of input in form is "fax" but you write as

```
request.getParameter("telefax")
```

Comment: Since, this is obviously not the solution for the problem he asked for, a comment would've been enough. EDIT: Aaaaaand I just recognized, that you would need more reputation to comment. So, nevermind ...

Comment: Yes i need more reputation that is why i cannot comment :(